# Can't login to facebook with Motorola Cliq (MB200)

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, facebook-login

we're trying to port our app to the Motorola Cliq (don't ask me why). It's running Android 2.3.7. We're using Facebook's Android SDK 3.0 and Facebook's login button.

After attempting login, in onSessionStateChanged(), I get:

```
state=CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED, session={Session state:CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[]}, appId:464891386855067}
```

Facebook login is working fine on other 2.3 devices (and above).

Any ideas?

EDIT:
I'm also getting an exception back:

```
exception=com.facebook.FacebookAuthorizationException
```

Comment: What version of the Facebook app do you have on the device? Also, in your Session.StatusCallback, can you print out the exception parameter? Usually a transition to the state CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED is caused by some exception.

Comment: Thanks Ming, post edited w/ exception=com.facebook.FacebookAuthorizationException.

Comment: Is there any details in the exception? Like if you did a exception.getMessage() or printed the stacktrace?

Comment: It started working ... no changes on my end ...